# Função upload multi attchements

Tags: sql, vba, upload, microsoft-access, programação-dinâmica

Estou a tentar criar uma função para fazer upload de vários ficheiros ao mesmo tempo mas mesmo só com um obtenho um erro.
O que poderei estar a programar mal?

```
'FILE DIALOG OPENS UPLOAD PANEL
Private Sub Comando715_Click()
Call Selectfile
End Sub
```

A função criada é a seguinte:

```
Public Function Selectfile() As String
Dim Fd As FileDialog
Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With Fd
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Por favor selecione as fotos desta peça a anexar"
If .Show = True Then
    Selectfile = .SelectedItems(1)
    Me.Anexo412 = Selectfile
Else
    Exit Function
End If
Set Fd = Nothing
End With
End Function
```

O erro que me dá no VBA está na seguinte linha

```
Dim Fd As FileDialog
```

Alguém me poderá ajudar a completar o código?

Answer (score 0):

O obejeto `FileDialog` é fornecido pela biblioteca `Microsoft Office [Nº da versão] Object Library`. Provavelmente a referência não foi definida ou está corrompida.

Para ativar:

```
Editor VBA > Ferramentas > Referências
```

E marque a biblioteca.

Comment: Resolveu esse problemas contudo aparece um outro erro que passo a colocar cá.
`Me.Anexo412 = Selectfile`

O erro especificado é: 
**Erro em tempo de execuçã '438':**
**O objeto não aceita esta propriedade ou método**

Comment: O ficheiro que estou a tentar carregar no `Anexo412` é um ficheiro **.jpeg**, como posso restringir o tipo de ficheiros que posso seleccionar, para não seleccione ficheiros de tipos que sejam indevidos?

Comment: Você precisa adicionar o anexo selecionado a alguma propriedade do obejto `Anexo412`. Lista completa de propriedades [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243266(v=office.12).aspx). Provavelmente é a `FilelName`. Ficaria assim: `Me.Anexo412.FileName = Selectfile`

Comment: Obrigado já esta exportar para o campo definido.
O codigo actual é:

Comment: @ Lúcio Rubens
'FILE DIALOG OPENS UPLOAD PANEL
Private Sub Comando715_Click()
Call Selectfile
End Sub
'FUNÇÃO CAIXA DE SELEÇÃO
Public Function Selectfile() As String
Dim Fd As FileDialog
Dim Filtro As FileDialogFilters
Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With Fd
    'FILTRO DE IMAGENS
    Set Filtro = .Filters
    With Filtro
    .Clear
    .Add "Imagens", "*.jpeg;*.jpg"
    End With
    'NÃO PERMITIR MULTI-SELEÇÃO
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    'DEFINE O NOME DA CAIXA DE SELEÇÃO
    .Title = " Por favor introduza as fotos da peça"
    If .Show = True Then

Comment: Este é o resto do codigo
    **'CODIGO DE COLOCAÇÃO DE ANEXO EM FORMULÁRIO
        Selectfile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Me.Anexo412.DefaultPicture = Selectfile
    Else
    MsgBox "Clicou no botão cancelar ao escolher imagem."
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set Fd = Nothing
End With
End Function**

Comment: Será que me pode ajudar a fazer com que esta função suporte multi selecção e carregar até 8 anexos com a mesma função.
Falta apenas esse pequeno pormenor para estar resolvida a minha questão.

Comment: O ideal é você criar uma nova pergunta, postando seu código atual.. Pois a dúvida dessa pergunta foi sobre o erro no objeto. @FredericoOliveira

Comment: E por favor, marca como "aceito" a resposta, para ajudar outros usuários com o mesmo problema!

Comment: Como faço para "aceitar a resposta"?

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como o StackOverflow funciona. Mas para aceitar basta clicar no ícone ao lado da resposta

Comment: (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72684/carregar-multi-attachements-em-varios-anexos-em-formul%C3%A1rio)