# Carregar multi-attachements em varios anexos em formulário

Tags: sql, vba, upload, microsoft-access, programação-dinâmica

Estou a tentar criar uma função para fazer upload de vários ficheiros ao mesmo tempo mas julgo que por estar a escolher a função seguinte não anexa verdadeiramente o ficheiro mas sim cria um preview.

**Na minha optica acho que o que está mal no codigo é:**

```
Me.Anexo412.DefaultPicture = Selectfile
```

E aparte disso necessito de carregar até 8 ficheiros (max) em simultâneo pois são 8 o máximo de ficheiros que se pode anexar neste formulário.

**Fica aqui o código para vossa analise**

```
'FILE DIALOG OPENS UPLOAD PANEL
Private Sub Comando715_Click()
Call Selectfile
End Sub
'FUNÇÃO CAIXA DE SELEÇÃO
Public Function Selectfile() As String
Dim Fd As FileDialog
Dim Filtro As FileDialogFilters
Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With Fd
'FILTRO DE IMAGENS
Set Filtro = .Filters
With Filtro
.Clear
.Add "Imagens", "*.jpeg;*.jpg"
End With
'NÃO PERMITIR MULTI-SELEÇÃO
.AllowMultiSelect = True
'DEFINE O NOME DA CAIXA DE SELEÇÃO
.Title = " Por favor introduza as fotos da peça"
If .Show = True Then
'CODIGO DE COLOCAÇÃO DE ANEXO EM FORMULÁRIO
Selectfile = .SelectedItems(1)
Me.Anexo412.DefaultPicture = Selectfile
Else
MsgBox "Clicou no botão cancelar ao escolher imagem."
Exit Function
End If
Set Fd = Nothing
End With
End Function
```

Algum de vocês poderá me ajudar nesta questão?

Comment: @rray Can you help me out?

Comment: I tried this code
`Me.Anexo412 = Selectfile`
Doesn't does anything.... I tried the code `Me.Anexo.DefaultPicture = Selectfile`
Can anyone give me some idea how to do it? I've read a lot of internet posts but cant find the answer.
Any ideas.